# How can I access ajax response data in global object with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

I have been already tired this code but I can access ajax response data in assets variable how can I access it.

```js
const JSONURL = 'json';
var assets = {};

$(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: `${JSONURL}/assets.json`,
    type: "GET",
    success: function(data) {
      assets.data
    }
  })
});

console.log(assets);
```

Comment: Can you edit the question to be more clear. Neither the description or your code snippet make it obvious as to exactly what outcome you're trying to achieve

Comment: I presume you meant `assets = data`, not `assets.data`?

Comment: People are trying to help you understand that the statement `assets.data` does nothing, and that's true without regard to conducting an ajax operation. It's a do-nothing statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Custom Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent). In this case, on ajax success you want to fire a custom event. Think of it as an event, you define. In this case let's fire a custom event called `my-first-fancy-custom-event` on the window object. Then on the other hand you add the event listener (like any other event) but in this case you listen on the name you have defined, again it's `my-first-fancy-custom-event`.

```js
window.addEventListener(
  "my-first-fancy-custom-event", 
  function(event) {
    // you will only need assets or event.detail
    // this is just to show both ways to get the data
    // chose one also in the ajax success method
    // my personal choice is to avoid global variables like assets
    console.log('assets: ', assets);
    console.log('event.detail: ', event.detail);
  }
);



const JSONURL = 'json';
var assets = {};

$(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: `${JSONURL}/assets.json`,
    type: "GET",
    success: function(data) {
      // fire custom event here passing the data in detail object
      // see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent
      // for more details
      assets = data; // so either set the data to the global assets variable
      window.dispatchEvent(
        new CustomEvent(
          "my-first-fancy-custom-event",
          { detail: { myData: data } } // just add here and empty object => {}
                                       // if you chose global variable
        );
      );
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: I suspect the OP will be looking through this answer trying to figure out where the code updates the global `assets` variable, which was the topic of the question.

Comment: Yep, thank @Pointy! I just figured out. I'll have to update

Comment: I am not satisfied

Answer (score 0):

if your api response is JSON then you need to just edit

```
success: function(data) {
      assets.data = data
    }
```

you can also bind `assets` object with window object for making `assets` to  global scope

Comment: nice way but I want add without any key like assets.add() or assets.push() like that

Comment: ```assets.data = data``` this statement is not use any key @Nipu

Comment: I can't get value without any key